# Find when reCAPTCHA is reloaded

Tags: javascript, php, captcha, recaptcha

I'm doing some research in CAPTCHAs' usability and I'm currently looking at reCAPTCHA from Google.

I'm trying to count the number of times a user reload a CAPTCHA because he can't solve it, but I can't seem to find a way to get that information.
Basically, every time the user ask for a new CAPTCHA, I'd like to increment a counter.
I'm using JS/PHP.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML injected by the reCaptcha in PHP contains the following HTML for the reload button:

```
<a title="Get a new challenge" id="recaptcha_reload_btn"><img alt="Get a new challenge" src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/img/red/refresh.gif" id="recaptcha_reload" height="17" width="25"></a>
```

This means you can add a Javascript event listener to the button and count the number of times it is clicked. This example uses jQuery to increment a global variable:

```
var recaptcha_reloaded = 0;
$(document).on("click", "#recaptcha_reload_btn", function() {
    recaptcha_reloaded++;
});
```

How you send this information once it is captured is up to you. One possibility is injecting it into a hidden input field on a form before it is submitted.

Also note that this only counts the number of times the button was *clicked*, not the number of times it was actually reloaded. There is a delay between clicking the recaptcha reload button and when the recaptcha is actually reloaded, and additional clicks during this interval will be ignored.

Comment: I can't seem to be able to make the JavaScript works with the injected HTML.
Even a simple on click alert is not registered apparently.
Where should I put the script? I've tried various places with no luck.

Also, I'm not sure we actually have the same code for reCAPTCHA.
The HTML injected in mine is actually : 
<div class="rc-button goog-inline-block rc-button-reload" title="Get a new challenge" role="button" style="-webkit-user-select: none;" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="0"></div>

I've tried changing #recaptcha_reload_btn to .rc-buttonreload, but no luck either.

Comment: I wasn't using the correct code from Google, thus why it wasn't working. I was using "<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="$mykey"></div>" instead of the PHP library.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click','#recaptcha_reload',function(){
    try {
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', location.href,
               'Captcha reload', '']);
    } catch(e) {}
});
```

Comment: Can you please edit your answer to include why this solves the question?